# jquery , razor view, and sql database

Tags: jquery, asp.net, razor

I am new to asp.net and razor. I am trying to get the field called product to have autocomplete with results from the database.

I have created autocomplete.cs model and the ticket controller was already in project so i just added the action. Then the new.cshtml I had added the code.  I am lost on what is wrong. Any help is appreciated.

The issue is when i go to new.cshtml page and jquery does not work and textbox does nothing. It screws up the hidden fields which i used jquery to hide. It shows up.

Here is the auto complete.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace HelpDesk.Models
{
public class PartNumber
{
    public string[] GetPartNumber()
    {
        List<string> partnumber = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RASConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select * from pltjones.dbo.inv_master", con);
            SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                partnumber.Add(reader["part_no"].ToString());
            }
        }
        return partnumber.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then here is the ticket controller that was already made in this application. I am doing a snipplet of what i added.

```
  public ActionResult Autocomplete(string term)
    {
        var items = new PartNumber().GetPartNumber();

        var filteredItems = items.Where(
            item => item.IndexOf(term, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
            );
        return Json(filteredItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here is the razor view new.cshtml

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#product')
    .each(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("Autocomplete")'
        });
    });
   });
```

```
 <tr id="trEmail">
    <td colspan="2">
        <label for="product">Enter product: </label>
        <input type="text" name="product" id="product" />
</tr>
```

Comment: Make sure that JQuery is properly loaded into your page new.chtml with this code in <script>..</script> section. `if (jQuery) {  
 
   alert("jQuery library is loaded!");
 
} else {
 
   alert("jQuery library is not found!");
 
}`

Comment: It seems you include jquery not correct(include multiple times). I tried your code and it worked! Can you show the error log in browser console?

Comment: Console shows this as the error TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

source: '/Tickets/Autocomplete'

Comment: Okay i think i got the console error gone as i added this in the code as I found out that it was not adding it correctly but still pulls up nothing is there anything else I can do ?                                                                                                                                       <script src="../../js/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../../js/jquery.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: Okay I am getting a public IP address on the application and willing to offer money on person that can walk me through what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said what autocomplete you are using, but in any case there is no need to call `.each()` since there will only be one match, so just use this instead:

```
$('#product').autocomplete(... etc ...)
```

And you have not provided any code for what to do when someone chooses an item, eg

```
$('#product').autocomplete({
    source: // as above
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#product").val(ui.item.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: i thought it would pull from the public action result autocomplete which then uses the method to grab from the database. Adding above code correct the jquery issue with other drop down but still does not work

Comment: The text box just needs to show the parts number from database and then I have a form that submits it. If this was an aspx page i could do it easy but with it being razor i had to find another option to use to get the same results the ajax toolkit extender could have done.